# BeautifulSoup HTML table parsing, table within a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am using BeautifulSoup to parse data from HTML tables.
Usally the HTML runs like that:

```
        <tr><td width="35%"style="font-style: italic;">Owner:</td><td>MS 'CEMSOL' Schifffahrtsgesellschaft mbH & Co. KG</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="35%"style="font-style: italic;">Connecting District:</td><td>HAMBURG (HBR)</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="35%"style="font-style: italic;">Flag:</td><td>CYPRUS</td></tr>
        <tr><td width="35%"style="font-style: italic;">Port of Registry:</td><td>LIMASSOL</td></tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

But Then there are sections:

```
<table class="table1"><thead><tr><th style="width: 140px" class="veristarTableUHeader">Classification</th><th class="top"><a href="#top">Top</a></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td width="35%" valign="top"style="font-style: italic;">Main Class Symbols:</td><td>I<img src='/asms2-portlet/images/particulars/croixsoul.gif'/> Hull&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<img src='/asms2-portlet/images/particulars/croixsoul.gif'/>Mach</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="35%" valign="top"style="font-style: italic;">Service Notations:</td><td valign="top">
        <table class="empty">
            <tr>

                <td>General cargo ship /cement carrier</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td width="35%" valign="top"style="font-style: italic;">Navigation Notations:</td><td>Unrestricted navigation<br></td></tr>
    <tr><td width="35%" valign="top"style="font-style: italic;">Additional Class Notation(s):</td><td><img src='/asms2-portlet/images/particulars/croixsoul.gif'/> AUT-UMS , <img src='/asms2-portlet/images/particulars/croixsoul.gif'/> ICE CLASS IA</td></tr>
    <tr><td width="35%" valign="top"style="font-style: italic;">Machinery:</td><td valign="top">
        <table class="empty">
            <tr>
                <td width="20"><img src='/asms2-portlet/images/particulars/croixsoul.gif'/></td>
                <td>MACH</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td></tr>

</tbody></table>
```

The source .txt : [ShipData](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9i7dFxjj8nGcjlJV1F4NnpyMGc)
The problem is, there is an extra `<tr>` tag, which messes the answers up by  doubling one table column **General cargo ship /cement carrier** It adds it twice to **Values list** as tr has a new table within it. `['12536D', '9180401', 'CEMSOL', 'C4WH2', 'General cargo ship', "MS 'CEMSOL' Schifffahrtsgesellschaft mbH & Co. KG", 'HAMBURG (HBR)', 'CYPRUS', 'LIMASSOL', 'I Hull\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0\xc2\xa0Mach', 'General cargo ship /cement carrier', 'General cargo ship /cement carrier', 'Unrestricted navigation', ' AUT-UMS ,  ICE CLASS IA', 'MACH']`

My code is the following:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
# from urllib import urlopen
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import socket
fm = open('ShipURL.txt', 'r')
Shiplinks = fm.readlines()  # Reads the line count from the first line.
check = ""
columnHeaders = ""
with open('ShipData.csv', 'wb')as f:  # Creates an empty csv file to which assign values.
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in Shiplinks:
        time.sleep(2)
        website = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', line)
        website = "".join(str(x) for x in website)
        print website
        if check != website:
            if website != "":
                check = website
                shipUrl = website
                while True:
                    try:
                        shipPage = urllib2.urlopen(shipUrl, timeout=1.5)
                    except urllib2.URLError:
                        continue
                    except socket.timeout:
                        print "socket timeout!"
                    break
                soup = BeautifulSoup(shipPage, "html.parser")  # Read the web page HTML
                table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "table1"})  # Finds table with class table1
                List = []
                columnRow = ""
                valueRow = ""
                Values = []
                for mytable in table:                                   #Loops tables with class table1
                    table_body = mytable.find('tbody')                  #Finds tbody section in table
                    try:                                                #If tbody exists
                        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')                #Finds all rows
                        for tr in rows:                                 #Loops rows
                            cols = tr.find_all('td')                    #Finds the columns
                            i = 1                                       #Variable to control the lines
                            for td in cols:                             #Loops the columns
            ##                  print td.text                           #Displays the output
                                co = td.text                            #Saves the column to a variable
            ##                    writer.writerow([co])                 Writes the variable in CSV file row
                                if i == 1:                              #Checks the control variable, if it equals to 1
                                    if td.text[-1] == ":":              # - : adds a ,
                                        columnRow += td.text.strip(":") + " , "  # One string
                                        List.append(td.text.encode("utf-8"))                #.. takes the column value and assigns it to a list called 'List' and..
                                        i += 1                                #..Increments i by one

                                else:
                                    # võtab reavahetused maha ja lisab koma stringile
                                    valueRow += td.text.strip("\n") + " , "
                                    Values.append(td.text.strip("\n").encode("utf-8"))              #Takes the second columns value and assigns it to a list called Values
                                #print List                             #Checking stuff
                                #print Values                           #Checking stuff
                    except:
                        print "no tbody"
                # Prints headings and values with row change.
                print columnRow.strip(",")
                print "\n"
                print valueRow.strip(",")
                # encode'ing hakkas jälle kiusama
                # Kirjutab esimeseks reaks veeru pealkirjad ja teiseks väärtused
                if not columnHeaders:
                    writer.writerow(List)
                columnHeaders = columnRow
                writer.writerow(Values)
                #
fm.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't exactly help you with not having to parse the extra table tag, but it sounds like you just need a solution so you don't keep getting 2 values in your list!

If I were you I would use a set which makes it so you only ever have one of the same values in your set.

To make a set in python 2.7 and higher it's:

```
List = {}
Values = {}
```

Note: If you are still stuck using a version prior to 2.7:

```
List = ([])
Values = ([])
```

and I would change the names maybe to:

```
Set        = {}
Set_values = {}
```

After doing that you can continue on to changing the last bit of your code to fix the problem!

```
if td.text[-1] == ":":                        
     columnRow += td.text.strip(":") + " , "  
     List.append(td.text.encode("utf-8"))     
     i += 1  
else:
   valueRow += td.text.strip("\n") + " , "
   Values.append(td.text.strip("\n").encode("utf-8"))
```

there I would use:

```
if td.text[-1] == ":":                        
     columnRow += td.text.strip(":") + " , "  
     Set.add(td.text.encode("utf-8"))   #<---Here is the change  
     i += 1 
else:
    valueRow += td.text.strip("\n") + " , "
    Set_values.add(td.text.strip("\n").encode("utf-8")) #<---Here is another change
```

doing this will make it so you ever only have one of the same value when writing to your CSV.

In case the CSV writer doesn't like sets and likes lists better, you can turn your sets into lists at the end of the file by doing this.

```
my_list  = list(Set)
my_list2 = list(Set_values)
```

Comment: Whoa, totally forgot the sets. But apparently it messes the code up. I have no idea why. I solved the problem using low level means. t=0 and if clause with t<1, then it can't take more than 1 td.

Comment: Ok great, that's a better solution anyways!  I've only used Selenium and not beautiful soup so I am not entirely sure how it handles the scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem with if clause t = 0 and if t < 1 then the program will append td.text element to the list. That guarantees that only one element will be added.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
# from urllib import urlopen
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import time
import socket
fm = open('ShipURL.txt', 'r')
Shiplinks = fm.readlines()  # Reads the line count from the first line.
check = ""
columnHeaders = ""
with open('ShipData.csv', 'wb')as f:  # Creates an empty csv file to which assign values.
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for line in Shiplinks:
        time.sleep(2)
        website = re.findall(r'(https?://\S+)', line)
        website = "".join(str(x) for x in website)
        print website
        if check != website:
            if website != "":
                check = website
                shipUrl = website
                while True:
                    try:
                        shipPage = urllib2.urlopen(shipUrl, timeout=1.5)
                    except urllib2.URLError:
                        continue
                    except socket.timeout:
                        print "socket timeout!"
                    break
                soup = BeautifulSoup(shipPage, "html.parser")  # Read the web page HTML
                table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "table1"})  # Finds table with class table1
                List = []
                columnRow = ""
                valueRow = ""
                Values = []
                for mytable in table:                                   #Loops tables with class table1
                    table_body = mytable.find('tbody')                  #Finds tbody section in table
                    try:                                                #If tbody exists
                        rows = table_body.find_all('tr')                #Finds all rows
                        for tr in rows:                                 #Loops rows
                            cols = tr.find_all('td')                    #Finds the columns
                            i = 1                                       #Variable to control the lines
                            t = 0
                            for td in cols:                             #Loops the columns
            ##                  print td.text                           #Displays the output
                                co = td.text                           #Saves the column to a variable
            ##                    writer.writerow([co])                 Writes the variable in CSV file row
                                if i == 1:                              #Checks the control variable, if it equals to 1
                                    if td.text[-1] == ":":              # - : adds a ,
                                        columnRow += td.text.strip(":") + " , "  # One string
                                        List.append(td.text.encode("utf-8"))                #.. takes the column value and assigns it to a list called 'List' and..
                                        i += 1                                #..Increments i by one

                                else:
                                    # võtab reavahetused maha ja lisab koma stringile
                                    if t<1:
                                        valueRow += td.text.strip("\n") + " , "
                                        Values.append(td.text.strip("\n").encode("utf-8"))              #Takes the second columns value and assigns it to a list called Values
                                        t += 1
                                #print List                             #Checking stuff
                                #print Values                           #Checking stuff
                    except:
                        print "no tbody"
                # Prints headings and values with row change.
                print columnRow.strip(",")
                print "\n"
                print valueRow.strip(",")
                # encode'ing hakkas jälle kiusama
                # Kirjutab esimeseks reaks veeru pealkirjad ja teiseks väärtused
                if not columnHeaders:
                    writer.writerow(List)
                columnHeaders = columnRow
                writer.writerow(Values)
                #
fm.close()
```